# How can I compare two generic collections?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How can I compare two generic collections? Here's my attempt with two string arrays, but it doesn't return true.

```
namespace genericCollections
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] xx = new string[] { "gfdg", "gfgfd", "fgfgfd" };
            string[] yy = new string[] { "gfdg", "gfgfd", "fgfgfd" };
            Console.WriteLine(ComparerCollection(xx, yy).ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool ComparerCollection<T>(ICollection<T> x, ICollection<T> y)
        {
            return x.Equals(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
bool arraysAreEqual = xx.SequenceEqual(yy);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN documenation:

> The default implementation of Equals
>   supports reference equality only, but
>   derived classes can override this
>   method to support value equality.

In your case xx and yy are two different instances of string[] so they are never equal.
You'd have to override the .Equal() method of the string[]

But you can simply solve it by looping through the entire collection

```
static bool CompareCollection<T>(ICollection<T> x, ICollection<T> y)
{
       if (x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;

       for(int i = 0; i < x.Length,i++)
       {
           if (x[i] != y[i])
               return false;
       }

       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get elements that are in xx but not in xy by using LINQ:

```
 var newInXY = xx.Except(xy);
```